# Detect Sprites, they are in Shape or Not which random draw in Cocos2d

Tags: opengl, collision-detection, iphone, sprites, cocos2d-iphone

I have searched a lot on the web and found some helpful links but none solve my question.

[Link 1](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/244/cocos2d-collision-detection-against-a-random-shape) [Link 2](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/4403/how-to-detect-collisions-between-sprite-and-a-user-generated-shape-of-some-sort)

I have written some code, to draw lines with Touch methods, but I still have questions. Here is what I need help understanding.

**1 ->** Line has been cleared after draw complete (this might go in ccTouchesEnded method /  UIPangesture state End.)
**//I am not sure how to draw custom shapes with UIPanGesture or Touch methods.**

**2 ->** Is there any difference between capturing the whole game scenario for collision as like scheduleUpdate method and how do I find out if objects are colliding (these are randomly moving sprites and they have random shapes)?

**3 ->** How to Check whether a User drawn shape is closed or open (a convex shape or not)?

**4 ->** How to check random moving sprites inside drawn shape or outside?

Here I have some code, but I am not sure whether it's useful or not.

//This code is in init method

```
linePoints = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
// create a simple rendertexture node and clear it with the color white
rtx = [CCRenderTexture renderTextureWithWidth:winSize.width height:winSize.height];
rtx.position = CGPointMake(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);
[self addChild:rtx z:6 tag:101];

brush = [[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Line1.png"] retain];
brush.scale = 5.0f;
```

Draw line by touch move method.

```
 -(void) ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touchess withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
        UITouch *touchMyMinge = [touchess anyObject];
        CGPoint start = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace:touchMyMinge];
        CGPoint end = [touchMyMinge previousLocationInView:touchMyMinge.view];
        end = [[CCDirector sharedDirector]convertToGL:end];
        end = [self convertToNodeSpace:end];

        NSValue *value= [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:start];
        [linePoints addObject:value ];

        [rtx begin];
        float distance = ccpDistance(start, end);

        for (int i = 0; i < distance; i++)
        {
            float difx = end.x - start.x;
            float dify = end.y - start.y;
            float delta = (float)i / distance;
            [brush setPosition:ccp(start.x + (difx * delta), start.y + (dify * delta))];
            [brush visit];
        }
        [rtx end];
    }
```

I have attached two screen shots for more clarification.

Please help me about on my technical query.

[image: screen shot 1]
[image: Screen shot 2]